# Kendo Grid not rendering properly using Hierarchal Grids with many columns

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am currently using a Hierarchical Kendo Grid. You can see some exmples from kendo what I am trying to acomplish foud at this link: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy .

Now I have it all working properly as I want, except for how it renders. I have over 15 columns in the child grids within each row, and when I do a horizontal scroll to view them all, the styling all falls apart on the kendo UI.

[image]

If you look closely you will see that once a scroll occurs the headers of the parent rows do not stay fixed with the data, and the child grids, the rows extend beyond the rendered view. Has anyone come across this issue, and does any one know what I can do to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the child grid columns do not fit due to their number or large widths, then enable scrolling for the detail grids.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#width

Comment: Thanks. I did not want to get into overriding CSS. I understood why it was hanging out, but not how to properly correct it. -Thanks-

Comment: Nice, so I added scrollable to the detail grid and also left the last column for the main grid without a size. This adjusted everything nicely and gave me the desired affect. Thanks.